# Is there an operator in C where I can "and-equals"?

Tags: c

I am wondering whether there is some operator in C where you can change this code:
`tie = tie && (candidates[i].votes == min);` into something like `tie &= (candidates[i].votes == min);`?

I am just asking because of aesthetic sake and because I am relatively new to C programming.

I know in Python you could just `*=` but I do not know if that is also valid in C.

Please let me know!

Comment: Did you try it? What error did you get? (Hint: `&=` is a bitwise operator)

Comment: @tadman I did try it. It somewhat works as intended but it did not work with the specific example above. But when I tried it on some test code, it did work. However, my other coding friends told me that I should keep the original as it is easier to read.

Comment: The original is easier to read. When you've tried something it's helpful to say that you have, and to show us the code you tried. We can iterate on something you've got, we can only speculate on what you *might* have done.

Comment: You could also do `if (tie) { tie = ... }` which is perhaps more clear, it really depends on the overall context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not.

I would suggest the original instead of `*=` because in my opinion it is clearer.